# Clang++ SCOPED_CAPABILITY produces "warning: releasing mutex 'locker' that was not held"

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, mutex, static-analysis

After attempting to implement the necessary annotations to an existing codebase, I was unable to remove a seemingly simple warning. I backed into the most simple example, and still no joy.

I have cut-and-pasted the `mutex.h` header exactly as specified at [Thread Safety Analysis](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html#mutexheader). I cannot seem to do a scoped lock without producing a warning. Here is the code:

```
#include "mutex.h"

#include <iostream>

// functions added just to complete the implementation
void Mutex::Lock()
{
}
void Mutex::GenericUnlock()
{
}

// test a scoped lock
void do_something(Mutex &m)
{
    auto locker = MutexLocker(&m);
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mutex my_mutex;
    do_something(my_mutex);
}
```

Compiling with `clang++ -o thread_static_analysis thread_static_analysis.cpp -std=c++17 -Wthread-safety` produces the following warning:

```
thread_static_analysis.cpp:18:1: warning: releasing mutex 'locker' that was not held [-Wthread-safety-analysis]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

Either (1) I am missing something, or (2) this is a false-positive that must be ignored until a clang implementation issue is resolved. A search for such issues has as-yet given no useful results.

```
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are potentially creating a copy of temporary `MutexLocker` object in

```
auto locker = MutexLocker(&m);
```

(or thread safety analysis *thinks* you are creating it). The temporary is then destroyed and calls `m.Unlock()`. Then at the end of the function the `locker` object is destroyed and calls `m.Unlock()` again (thus causing a double release error).

Comment: Thank you. I had just done some work with move operations, and evidently had that stuck in my head. While a compiler should make this a move assignment, from a static analysis standpoint this is copy assignment, hence temporaries. I changed it to `MutexLocker locker(m);` and all is good.

Comment: @JohnJones actually most (all?) compilers would get rid of the temporary anyway (even in C++98 mode) but TSA treats the construct conservatively.